# Ways to convert tabular data (.csv) to RGB image?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, tabular

I am looking for possible ways of converting Tabular data to Images for inputs to a 2D CNN architecture. There’s a paper where they converted tabular data into an image with a shape of (60,60,3) where 60 is the total number of features of the csv file. They have taken 60x3= 180 rows for each of the image where first 60 rows are mapped to the first channel, the chunk of second and third 60 rows are mapped into second and third channel of the image. Here’s the link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.01971.pdf

Is there any other possible ways to transform tabular data to images based on the method described above? I know about DeepInsight but don’t don’t want to go with that. Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: do you know what a dataframe is and how to use it? since you have a question about the paper, have you contacted the authors yet?

Comment: I know about dataframe and implemented the method the authors has followed in this paper. But I don’t want to go with this paper as it’s not suited for my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the requirements of the CNN architecture are, but it's trivial to create an image from tabular data in python using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`. This example creates some dummy data, creates an ordered array from that data, then generates an image from one the dimensions.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# dummy tabular data, in this case a bunch of lists
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
x, y, a, b, c = [], [], [], [], []
for i in range(60):
    for j in range(60):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(j)
        a.append(rng.random())
        b.append(rng.random())
        c.append(rng.random())

# assuming the tabular data is not ordered, we need
# to create ordered indexes for the data.
unique_x = sorted(set(x))
unique_y = sorted(set(y))

count_x = len(unique_x)
count_y = len(unique_y)

# create ordered numpy ndarray to store that
data = np.zeros((count_x, count_y, 3))
for i, val_x in enumerate(x):
    idx_x = unique_x.index(val_x)
    idx_y = unique_y.index(y[i])
    data[idx_x, idx_y] = a[i]
    data[idx_x, idx_y] = b[i]
    data[idx_x, idx_y] = c[i]

# select the a dimension of the data to display
dimension_a = data[:, :, 0]

# display the 'a' dimension as an image using imshow
plt.imshow(dimension_a, cmap='gray') 
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('dimension_a_image.png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
plt.show()
```